# How to stop service on button click event

Tags: android, service

I am using following `service` to play sound in my app when app start sound start and when user click on any `button` in menu its stop. But I am facing some problems. Like if user open app and without pressing any `button` in app menu he press menu `button` on mobile sound not stop. And if app start and call or message is coming on mobile still sound play in background. How to stop `service` on these 2 events?

Service code-

```
public class PlayAudio extends Service{
private static final String LOGCAT = null;
MediaPlayer objPlayer;

public void onCreate(){
super.onCreate();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
objPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.test);
}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
objPlayer.start();
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
if(objPlayer.isLooping() != true){
Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
}
return 1;
}

public void onStop(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}

public void onPause(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
public void onDestroy(){
objPlayer.stop();
objPlayer.release();
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent objIndent) {
return null;
}
}
```

When my app start from splash activity I starting audio like-

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.splash);
       objIntent = new Intent(this, PlayAudio.class);
       startService(objIntent);
       new Handler().postDelayed(csRunnable2, 5000);  
       }
```

Then in main menu activity stopping it when user press any button-

```
hist = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hist);
        hist.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                objIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PlayAudio.class);
                stopService(objIntent);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, History.class));
                finish();
```

And please tell me where I have to do changes?

Comment: Stopself() method called

Comment: You should explicitly call it on click of button also. Where have you done that? Is this your complete code you posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override onStop() and onPause() methods of your Activity like this:

```
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class));
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class));
}
```

Or

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    // send a message to service to set sound player on pause(using Handler)
}

 @Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    // send a message to service to resume sound playing
}
```

Comment: try to override onBackPressed() method too:

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class));
    }

Comment: Try to do the same thing, but call super.onBackPressed() after stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class));

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273539/android-service-running-after-pressing-home-key

Answer (score 1):

```
start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
    }
});

stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue, you can refer to this post,

[Android service running after pressing Home key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4273539/1626878)

For your second issue, you should create a receiver that listens for the incoming call.

and in the `onReceive()` method of the receiver, you could stop the service.

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889095/1626878) for details about how to create an incoming receiver.

Using this, you can start the service again once the call is disconnected.

Comment: answer you provide for the first issue not looking good. How I chande my code into that?

Answer (score 0):

just call

```
stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourService.class));
```

this will stops the Your Service

Comment: where you want to stop your service?